# Shortcut Shift + F2 for MS Access doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, microsoft-access

I started to learn MS Access.

On a Youtube video they said that when you use the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> you get a zoom window which is interesting when you want to type a long text. When I try this shortcut it activates "airplane mode". That is the standard shortcut on my keybord.

I searched on Google and Youtube for a solution, but I can't find it. How can I use the Access shortcuts for Access 2019?

I read that the Access shortcuts should work when you have a subscription for Office. I have a subscription for Office 365 but it just doesn't work. None of the `F`-functions work in Access.

Normally I should get the help menu by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, but when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> my laptop goes into "sleeping mode". What can I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SU. Your question is a bit unclear. Can you please update your post and explain what exactly you mean by "zoom window", maybe share a screenshot of the video in question? Also could you please add a screenshot of this "airplane mode"? [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-for-access-70a673e4-4f7b-4300-b8e5-3320fa6606e2)'s Microsoft support article showing MS Access. According to the doc it's valid for all versions from Access 2003 to 365.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> it activates "airplane mode" [and] when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> my laptop goes into "sleeping mode".

While admittedly a bit of a guess (as you don't mention the model of laptop in your question), it sounds like the manufacturer may have chosen to hijack at least some of the default F-keys for other functions related to the laptop. In cases like this, there is often a special key (perhaps marked as <kbd>Fn</kbd>) that will allow "normal" operations of these keys. So <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> might become e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, while <kbd>F1</kbd> might become <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: Anaksunaman, Thank you for your answer. I just tried your solution and it works. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got it figured out. =)